# headerView and footerView register

Tags: swift3, header, tableview, footer

it seems like that it doesn't matter whether i register or not when i'm using a tableView header and footer.
like:
tableView.register(DeclarationCellHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: self.headerId)
my question is how to use this register thing, do we have to register to use them

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you have to register the xib for the using them in UITableView Header

Add following codes to your ViewController

```
// inside ViewController viewDidLoad()

override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        nibName = UINib(nibName: "headerViewCellIdentifire", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nibName, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "headerViewCellIdentifire")

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource{

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "headerViewCellIdentifire") as! TableViewHeaderFooterView

        return view

    }


}
```

Comment: but i created the tableview by code not xib or storyboard, and it works without writing the register sentence. is it not necessary  when using code to create a cell ?

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to use only title ... No need to register.
- But if you want to custom your view, you have to register in viewDidLoad you view from Xib. "registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:"
- Dont forget to change class name in xib from inspector, to "UITableViewHeaderFooterView"